# How to control / disable low level battery on bluetooth mouse

Tags: mouse, indicator, bluetooth, battery

I have a little problem with my Kesington Bluetooth Mouse on Ubuntu 12.10.

Ubuntu 12.10 considers my bluetooth mouse battery as a system battery as if it was the main laptop battery (so I have two on the battery indicator, the main and the bluetooth one). When it runs low level, near to die, battery, my laptop acts as if it was the main battery and I must quickly stop bluetooth and continue on the touchpad if I want to work.

Can anyone help me? Maybe I prefer to disable the battery control over the mouse, I don't care about it, I know it is fully charged, but Ubuntu always starts on 33% or less, I just want to work with it and when it will be battery-off I will recharge the batteries.

Many thanks in advance.

Alberto.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is not a solution, but for me, it solved my problem. I don't like the Unity desktop, so, I have changed it for LXDE and the battery monitoring has disappeared, now I have added to the panel a main battery monitor and only looks for the laptop battery and my bluetooth mouse is working properly (funny, but on Unity it was battery dead and on LXDE is alive).
As I said, it is not a solution, but, Unity is so so so slow and now I have gained a faster desktop and one problem less.
Hope there will be a solution for the "main" problem I posted.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but with Logitech DiNovo Edge keyboard. A bug has just been filed here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1086746

Quick answer : with the Bluetooth USB dongle shipped with the keyboard, it works fine and the keyboard battery is not detected. So I'm using it even if bluetooth is on on the laptop. The laptop bluetooth does not interfere.

Hopefully your case could help, you can add your experience and mark yourself as affected by this bug, or declare another bug and relate it to this one?

I've used my keyboard on Windows, with the Logitech driver, and it appears that the battery level is known by the driver. So in Ubuntu, the fact that a battery is detected may not be the wrong point, because such information is actually provided. But the fact that the battery is interpreted as the laptop one is wrong. And the charge level is wrong too, anyway.